# Why is the lone pair of electrons of nitrogen delocalised in quinoline?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am aware that the lone pair of electrons on nitrogen in pyridine is located in an orbital which is not parallel to the orbitals of carbon and hence it is not delocalised. How do they then delocalise in quinoline?

Comment: Exactly the same

Answer (score 3):

> **Your question:** I am aware that the lone pair of electrons on nitrogen in pyridine is located in an orbital which is not parallel to the orbitals of carbon and hence it is not delocalised. How do they then delocalise in quinoline?

I am a little confused about your question. Your title definitely indicate lone pair of nitrogen in quinoline is delocalized. To me, your question indicate it may of may not delocalize. Nonetheless, my answer is it **do not** delocalize (behave same as in pyridine).

The following is what most recent book about chemistry of heterocycles (Ref.1) has to say:

> **Physical Properties:** Quinoline is a colorless, hygroscopic liquid with a smell similar to pyridine. Quinoline is only sparingly soluble in water but miscible with nearly all organic solvents. Quinoline when exposed to light for a longer duration turns yellow and subsequently brown. The bp of quinoline at $\pu{760 mm}$ was found to be $\pu{237.1°C}$. Its freezing point was reported to be $\pu{−14.94°C}$, whereas the calculated value was $\pu{−14.85°C}$. The density of quinoline at $\pu{25°C}$ has been reported to be $1.08981$. The dipole moment of quinoline has been determined both in the vapor phase and in the liquid phase. In the vapor phase the dipole moment was $\pu{2.29 D}$, whereas in carbon tetrachloride it was found to be $\pu{2.27 D}$.
>
> Quinoline is a base because the lone pair of electrons on the nitrogen atom of pyridine is not involved in the formation of a delocalized $\pi$-molecular orbital. Quinoline is aromatic with a resonance energy of 47.3 and is considered to be a resonance hybrid of the following contributing structures (Figure **A**):

[image: Quinoline]

> Structures **I**, **II**, and **III** are of lower energy; however, additional charged structures **IV–VIII** are also possible because of the presence of the electronegative nitrogen atom. The dipole moment of quinoline is $\pu{2.10 D}$, which confirms the presence of charge separation within the ring.

As in the case of pyridine, quaternization of the $\ce{N}$-atom of quinoline is also common because of the availability of its lone pair to the suitable electrophile. This markedly enhances the susceptibility of the hetero-ring to nucleophilic attack. If quinoline is quaternized with benzoyl chloride and the product treated with potassium cyanide, the dihydroquinoline derivative (**IX**, [a Reissert compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissert_reaction)) is formed (Figure **B**). Compounds of this type are of interest in that they undergo a complex hydrolytic cleavage on treatment with concentrated hydrochloric acid, giving eventually quinoline-2-carboxylic acid (**X**) and an aldehyde (Ref.2).

**References:**

1. Vishnu Ji Ram, Arun Sethi, Mahendra Nath, Ramendra Pratap, In *The Chemistry of Heterocycles: Chemistry of Six-to-Eight-Membered N, O, S, P and Se Heterocycles*; Elsevier Ltd.: Amsterdam, The Netherlands, 2019, “Chapter 2.3: Six-Membered Isolated and Benzo-Fused Heterocycles with One Nitrogen Atom,” p. 77 (ISBN: 978-0-12-819210-8; and DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/C2018-0-04877-X).
2. P. W. G. Smith, A. R. Tatchell, In *Organic Chemistry for General Degree Students, Vol.2: Aromatic Chemistry*; First Edition, Pergamon Press Ltd.: Oxford, United Kingdom, 1969  (ISBN: 978-0-08-012948-8 and DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/C2013-0-05520-X).